# Convert MySQL Query to Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi can you help me convert this query into Laravel's Eloquent.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `prgrm_accreds` 
JOIN `acad_prgrms` ON `acad_prgrms.id` = `prgrm_accreds.acad_prgrm_id`
JOIN `schools` ON `schools.id` = `acad_prgrms.school_id`
WHERE `prgrm_accreds.accred_status_id` = 3
AND `schools.id` = 1
```

I would like to know how many `acad_prgrms` is there with an `accred_status_id` of 3 and an `id' of 1 from the` schools` table.

[Here's my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfwCu.jpg)

I would like to rely on Laravel's use of relationships with models and not use 'DB' or 'Join'.

I want to learn how to extract data from the 3 connected tables with the conditions stated above.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851917/convert-mysql-to-eloquent

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)? If so, which parts of it are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

here it is

```php
\DB::table('prgrm_accreds')
      ->join('acad_prgrms', 'acad_prgrms.id', 'prgrm_accreds.acad_prgrm_id')
      ->join('schools', 'schools.id', 'acad_prgrms.school_id')
      ->where(['prgrm_accreds.accred_status_id'=> 3,'schools.id'=>1])
      ->count();
```